# Does agent Ward still have the disk? (Agents of Shield Spoilers)

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In *Turn, Turn, Turn* (S1E17)

> Skye writes all the secret information on the Bus to a disk and deletes the originals to keep it from falling into enemy hands.  She then gives the disk to Ward for safekeeping because she hasn't been trained to withstand torture.

Later in the episode,

> Ward is shown to kill Agent Hand, and release Garrett who is apparently the Clairvoyant, presumably making him either an agent of Hydra or under their control.

At the end of the episode does Agent Ward still have the disk?

Comment: I hope this is spoiler proofed enough, let me know if someone feels otherwise.

Comment: I have to go back and watch, but I feel like I remember Coulson telling Skye to go try to restore stuff at the end of the episode. This would have required the disk.

Comment: @phantom42 Not necessarily. Presumably there are other sources for firmware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Ward still has the disk at the end of the episode.

During *Providence* (S01E18),

> he provides the disk full of Simmons research to Raina so that she may resume Phase Three of Project Centipede.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the show has actively shown Skye giving hard disk to Ward, then, yes, Ward still has the disk. Ward is a bad guy, so he wouldn't drop the disk intentionally as the data would be valuable to the villain side. Also, it was shown that it was Ward who was asking about Asgardian weaponry, the drug, weather machine, gravitonium etc. Means, he was really seeking for the data.

However, the show has great reputation to mislead people. So, it can also be possible that the disk is broken now after Ward involved in fighting.

In the end, Coulson told Skye to restore firmware of the plane (which is required to fly), but firmware isn't classified data. It can be found with plane manual service discs. But, if firmware is also in that hard disk, Coulson's order doesn't reveal that it is with Skye now. In next episode, she may ask Ward to return hard disk. It's not a big deal. But, data may be gone to villain hands.

Comment: While it *might* be true Ward is a bad guy, I tend to not believe everything I'm told in a show run by Joss "The Herring MacGuffin" Whedon.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I find it especially uncompelling due to the last scene of the episode.

Comment: If there was a scene after the gunfire and the Hydra logo I missed it. :(

Comment: @MeatTrademark It was just a shot of Ward looking really pissed off. It was very weird.